# iPad simulator doesn't do the emails?

Tags: ipad, ios, sdk, ios-simulator

I am trying to test out email sending from my app on iPad simulator (using mailto:... URLs...) but it doesn't seem to work. Any way how I can test it? Or only on the "real thing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as I figured out if you try to send email via mailto:... openURL on iPad this doesn't seem to work in simulator. However, using MessageUI API actually does work..

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell you can only do it from a device. I think this is because the simulator does not come with the mail app installed and there are no settings to configure mail accounts which is what the device looks at when determining if it can send an e-mail. The strange thing though is that you always get a "success" when sending e-mail in the simulator even though the mail never really gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you send an email through an app on the simulator, you still get the mail sent notification, which can be accessed through the delegate. I haven't checked this in a while though.